# How do I add a specific user access to view a View Collection in Pocket base

Tags: pocketbase

I have a base collection where admin is adding data via post method (using api) and I have made a user specific view collections. My question is how do I grant only user1 access to view data from view collection of user1. I believe I have to make some custom api rules but I count not figure out how.

Any help?

Tried searching the docs but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep figured it out I actually refiened the schema. Now I have a Master collection and API rule

```
@reauest.auth.id = user.id
```

to view and list the records. Here user is the assigned user to a record. When user creates a record it automatically assigns it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a api rule yes. It could look like this: `@request.auth.id == 'id_of_the_user_to_be_granted_access'`

Comment: What do you mean by `api rule yes`? Where can I put the rule?

Comment: If you click on settings within a collections (the gear icon) then there will be a API Rules tab where you can configure who is allowed to read/write/update/search and so on.
For further reference please check the Documentation https://pocketbase.io/docs/api-rules-and-filters/